# Fixed size Layer symbols

Tags: qgis-3

When working in QGIS (3.4.6), how do I get a layer symbol(point) to remain its original size? In this case I have a point which enlarges in size when I zoom out, but it should remain it's original size. How does this work?

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "original size" and "enlarge". Basic setting is for symbols to remain the same size regardless of your zoom level.

Answer (score 3):

In `Layer Properties > Symbology` select the 'sub-symbology' (for lack of a better word), the to the right of the Size change the unit that it is displaying in. When it is displayed in milimetres it will always show the icon as being Xmm in size **on the display**. If you change this to Map Units then it will stay at a fixed, absolute size. Bear in mind this may rapidly become invisible when you zoom out.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Select "Map Units" for size option in Layer Styling window. Then, if layer has a field for point size value, you can define it using "Data defined override" button. But be careful, size unit should be the same as the **map's unit** (not as the layer's unit). If the map's unit is degree, value should be degree.

[image]